# I am getting 500 error on git clone

Tags: git, github

I am unable to clone a newly created repository. I am getting below error.

```
$ git clone https://github.xxxxx.com/zzzzzz.git
Cloning into 'zzzzzz'...
Username for 'https://github.xxxxxx.com': yyyyy
Password for 'https://yyyyy@github.xxxxxx.com':
remote: Internal Server Error.
remote:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.xxxxxx.com/zzzzz.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

I have successfully generated ssh keys and updated the key in github settings as per the instructions in the below URL

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

authentication was success when I executed the command: 
 git -T git@github.xxx.com

Also as per my understanding if we setup the ssh the git clone command should not ask for username and password. But it still asking for them.

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.xxxxx.com ([10.28.22.44]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Hi xxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. 
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3880, received 1696 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 19132.2, received 8363.0
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Is the repository public? Can I try it? `Internal Server Error` is most probably  an error on GitHub side.

Comment: @IonicăBizău : Thanks for your quick response. unfortunately it is a private repository, so it is not possible to access it externally.

Comment: Got it, but how does the url looks like? Try: `git clone git@github.com:owner/repo.git`

Comment: @IonicăBizău :  git clone git@github.com:owner/repo.git has worked. Thanks a lot for the solution. can you explain why http URL has not worked.

Comment: Can you still reproduce the previous error? Also, can you add exaclty the same url but replacing the sensitive words/parts?

Comment: I posted an answer. Don't forget to mark it, since it helped you already. :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is most probably a problem with GitHub service. I recommend [contacting them](https://github.com/contact) and explain what the problem is.

This is how Wikipedia explains the `500` response code:

> #### 500 Internal Server Error
>
> A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was 
>   encountered and no more specific message is suitable.

Basically, something went wrong on the GitHub endpoint.

---

**But**, since you already have set your SSH keys, you can use the ssh url to clone your repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:owner/repo.git
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, but in GitLab, and the answer to the problem is that GitLabis make a deploy.

```
Deploy in progress
Please try again in a few minutes.

Please contact your GitLab administrator if this problem persists.
```

So I was connected in a some hours and it is works.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference - I received the same error from Git CMD, trying instead through the windows powershell worked.

Answer (score -1):

try with connecting to VPN (at least try with 2 different locations) this worked for me. I was having the same problem

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).